# Get latest file from samba share using smbclient

Tags: python, python-3.x, smb

My directory contains the file and it's different versions out of which I want to pick the latest version which can either be sorted by date or by the revision number at the end of file name some thing like

`Myfile2001.txt`

Where `2001` is the revision number.

How can I get the latest file from samba-share directory using smb-client, I thought of using mask to take out all the names and pipe it to output and then to performing some searching algorithm to find the largest number (latest revision) and then use `smbclient get` to get the file, but this does not seems an optimal solution and it's too tedious. I wonder if there is any other way to do it ?

**EDIT:** I figured out an alternate way in python(Just for ease) to capture the output of `smbclient get ls` in text file or `STDOUT` and then use python to find the latest file's name. Now I cannot figure out how can I redirect the output of the above command to a text file or `STDOUT` to process it according to a logic.

Is there any way to do it? As `smbclient` does not allow the ioredirection, still I am stuck at the same point with newer approach. I have gone through `pysmb` but cannot rely on it as it is an experimental library, however, any solution with `pysmb` is also accepted to solve the purpose momentarily.

Comment: I am curious to know about the down vote. Is there anything I am wrong with ?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this issue using awk in bash script. Goal : download the most recent csv file

```
${SmbCmd} "ls <mask>" 2>/dev/null\
  | awk '{ if ($1 ~ "csv$") print $1 }' | sort | tail -1)
```

Where ${SmbCmd} have all the values to send to smb server, as the path to smbclient, the authentification method, the smb server name, the smb dir .... and finish by "--command", in long form

Of course, my csv files names have the creation date "name_yyyy-mm-dd.csv".

You can try something like that

```
${SmbCmd} "ls <mask>-*" | awk '{ if ($1 ~ "csv$") print $8$5$6";"$1 }'
```

But, the month isn't numeric